# enable software i2c on raspberry pi gpio

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, i2c, pigpio, gpiozero

I am trying to interface more than one sensor with Raspberry Pi Zero W, which communicate using i2c interface.

So far I am able to connect sensor to dedicated `i2c` and read the data.

Want to know how I can setup software `i2c` on RPi ZW `GPIO` pins (any) to connect sensor to my choice of GPIO. I am aware of `i2c-gpio` kernel module in raspbian, but how can I use it from python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i2c devices can be 'daisy chained' so you only need 2 pins:

[image]

Use 'i2cdetect -y 1' to list the addresses of each device:

[image]

Comment: How can I interpret address like this `TSL2561: 0x39(57)`. If `0x39` is TSL2561 address, then what is `(57)` in this case ?

Comment: 39 in hex is 57 decimal